# How to detect generic value task type ValueTask<T> using reflection

Tags: generics, .net-core

I am trying to find a Type property or method using which it would be possible to determine we are dealing with a generic ValueTask.

I have tested a few options but only the Name property seems to be indicative - generic value tasks start with string "ValueTask`":

https://dotnetfiddle.net/drzlrn

```cs
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("1:" + typeof(ValueTask).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(ValueTask<>)));
        Console.WriteLine("2:" + typeof(ValueTask).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(ValueTask<int>)));
        Console.WriteLine("3:" + typeof(ValueTask<>).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(ValueTask<>)));
        Console.WriteLine("4:" + typeof(ValueTask<int>).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(ValueTask<int>)));

        Console.WriteLine("5:" + typeof(ValueTask<>).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(ValueTask)));
        Console.WriteLine("6:" + typeof(ValueTask<int>).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(ValueTask)));
        Console.WriteLine("7:" + typeof(ValueTask<>).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(ValueTask<>)));
        Console.WriteLine("8:" + typeof(ValueTask<int>).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(ValueTask<int>)));

        Console.WriteLine("9:" + typeof(ValueTask<>).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(ValueTask<int>)));
        Console.WriteLine("10:" + typeof(ValueTask<int>).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(ValueTask<>)));

        Console.WriteLine("11:" + typeof(ValueTask<int>).IsGenericType);
        Console.WriteLine("12:" + typeof(ValueTask<int>).BaseType);
        Console.WriteLine("13:" + typeof(ValueTask<int>).Name);

        Console.WriteLine("14:" + ValueTaskMethod().Result);
        Console.WriteLine("15:" + ValueTaskAsyncMethod().Result);
    }

    public static ValueTask<int> ValueTaskMethod()
    {
        return new ValueTask<int>(10);
    }

    public static async ValueTask<int> ValueTaskAsyncMethod()
    {
        await Task.Delay(100).ConfigureAwait(false);
        return 10;
    }
}
```

```
1:False
2:False
3:True
4:True
5:False
6:False
7:True
8:True
9:False
10:False
11:True
12:System.ValueType
13:ValueTask`1
14:10
15:10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check for `type.IsGenericType`and if so, just try to call `GetGenericTypeDefinition()` on the specific type:

```cs
        Console.WriteLine("A:"+ typeof(ValueTask<>).GetGenericTypeDefinition());
        Console.WriteLine("B:"+ typeof(ValueTask<int>).GetGenericTypeDefinition());
        Console.WriteLine("C:"+ (typeof(ValueTask<int>).GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ValueTask<>)));
        Console.WriteLine("D:"+ (typeof(ValueTask<>).GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ValueTask<>)));

        Console.WriteLine("E:"+ (typeof(ValueTask<int>).GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ValueTask)));
        Console.WriteLine("F:"+ (typeof(ValueTask<>).GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ValueTask)));
```

```
A:System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1[TResult]
B:System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1[TResult]
C:True
D:True
E:False
F:False
```

Check the [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/pvqPWF) fork. Keep in mind you need a `type.IsGenericType` check before calling `GetGenericTypeDefinition`, otherwise you will get an exception on non-generic types!

Comment: Thanks. Please update your solution so that it  has full check before "Just", for other readers. E.g. typeVariable.IsGenericType && typeVariable.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ValueTask<>)